# LTS security policy for Thunderbird

Tags: 16.04, updates, security, thunderbird

I have a question regarding security updates in LTS editions, in concrete Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

What is the policy for offering security updates? Recently there was [released](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/52.9.0/releasenotes/) version 52.9.0 fixing some security issues, but not on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thunderbird is in the main repository, so it should get security updates for 5 years. Is this different for Thunderbird, or does it just take a little bit longer?

Comment: If you do not want to wait for ubuntu to release a fix, follow the I instructions on the page you gave to download and install manually

Answer (score 1):

Your link goes to the [specific](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2018-18/) notices if you follow the "security fixes" link and will show you the Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVE) number. Ubuntu has a [CVE](https://usn.ubuntu.com/) website where new are posted and there is also the [CVE tracker](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/?_ga=2.178772580.1398116973.1531142180-1877872371.1515150387) where you can search for packages (here is [Thunderbird](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/pkg/thunderbird.html)). 
And here you will find the same CVE numbers with a notice per Ubuntu release and its status.

Example: one of the CVE listed is [CVE-2018-12359](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-12359.html) and it has a fix for firefox, but needs triage for Thunderbird. Basically there is no fix for Ubuntu (yet but it will be there at some point in time).